# I can't create a template using create-react-app. getting the error message: a template was not provided. or ERROR 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

It's been many days that I am completely stuck and not able to create a react app with npx create-react-app my-app. I went through many Stakeoverflow conversations and tried in different ways but I keep on getting error messages : erro404 or error code1 or a template was not provided, and never succeed to create a template.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled Node version 16.13.1, my npm version is 8.1.2. 
I've tried :

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app 
npm install -g create-react-app
npm cache clean 
npm rebuild 
npm cache clean --force
npx clear-npx-cache
npm audit npm audit fix
npx create-react-app my-app --template[template-name]
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org 
sudo npm i -g create-react-app
```

I also checked the npm status on  https://status.npmjs.org/ and everything looks normal .
I don't know what else to try.
Do you have any idea of how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misread the syntax for the command line arguments. From [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/):

> You can now optionally start a new app from a template by appending --template [template-name] to the creation command.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried again with the correct syntax :  npx create-react-app my-app --template[template-name] and still get the same error message : A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.

Comment: Please go to the website I linked and read the syntax again.